# How do I center gadgets, gadget titles, and link lists in the footer section on blogger using HTML5 or CSS code?

Tags: css, html, center, footer, blogger

I have searched the interwebs for hours, including this site, for an answer to this question and have not found one, so I'm sorry if it's been answered before.

I am trying to center the gadgets (widgets?), gadget titles, and links. Basically, I want EVERYTHING centered in the footer section. I have a 3 column footer and am using the Watermark template in Blogger. I managed to center the sidebar content (or at least the images and the gadget titles) using CSS code I found on another forum. But that same code did not apply to the footer. All my searches have found info. and code that pertains the the post footer...but I'm concerned with the PAGE footer.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be helpful.

You can check out my website for a specific visual of the problem, but I run an erotica website and wouldn't want to break any content rules here. It is an 18+ website/NSFW. If listing the web address is not okay, but you need to see the site for a visual of the problem, please PM me for it. If is okay to list the website, let me know, so people can help me out with it.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For us to be able to assist you with your problem you will need to include all the relevant code that replicates the issue in your question. Linking to your website (whatever the content) is not sufficient as the link may go dead/the issue get fixed making the question redundant for other users experiencing a similar problem. For more info take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I don't have any relevant code to share. Do you want me to send you the section of HTML that creates the footer? I'm trying to add this to the CSS box in Blogger's advanced customization. This box has no code in it currently, as all the prior code I put in has suddenly disappeared, though the changes to the sidebar that the code made happed did not...weird.

Comment: I'll gladly post the HTML here for you to work with, but with almost 3000 lines of it, I need to know which sections to post. There's a big section of code that lists all the widgets in the footer. Here's a piece of that code:<b:section-contents id='footer-2-1'>
  <b:widget id='LinkList2' locked='false' title='Erotica Writers I Love' type='LinkList'>   I tried to post more of the code, but this box won't let me.

Comment: If you are using a tool to generate the HTML the best way to get the code would be to go to the page in your browser and use the "View source" option. Copy the area that is causing you problems (in this case the footer) along with the relevant CSS and use the edit button to add it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

try this css for your blocks

```
footer    {
    margin :0 auto 
}
```

Comment: #footer-left,
#footer-right {
 display: block;
 float: none;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#footer-right li {
 float: none;
 display: inline-block;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 padding-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

#footer-right li:last-child {
 border: none;
}   ---THIS IS MY FOOTER CODE RIGHT NOW